# Multiple submit while form page navigate to another page in JSF PrimeFaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

In Current page i have an confirm modal window.once modal window submitted it navigate to another page.
Navigation time takes too long.Tat time user can able to submit for multiple time.
I used Ajax progress bar that also loaded up to onsuccess.after that user can able to submit.
how can i restrict for single submit?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right you can just `show()` a modal dialog on top of everything and never `close()` it:

```
<p:commandButton ... onclick="PF('statusDialog').show()" action="..."/>

<p:dialog widgetVar="statusDialog" modal="true" draggable="false" closable="false" resizable="false" showHeader="false">
    <p:graphicImage name="/img/ajaxloadingbar.gif" />
</p:dialog>
```

You can of course omit the ajaxloadingbar.gif if you want. You can grab it from [here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/javax.faces.resource/demo/images/ajaxloadingbar.gif.xhtml).

You could also remove the dialog in case of an error:

```
<p:commandButton ... onclick="PF('statusDialog').show()" 
                     oncomplete="if(args &amp;&amp; args.validationFailed {PF('statusDialog').hide()}"
                     action="..."/>
```